# Kill an instace of an application from another instance

Tags: qt, multiple-instances, message-passing

I have a QtSingleApplication.

I've started an instance A.

Next I start an instance B.

B uses `sendmessage()` to send a message to A.

A uses this message ( received with `messageReceived()` signal )to determine whether B should continue running or not.

How do I inform B of this decision?

I had thought of inserting the process ID of B..with the message sent to A, and using this process ID, perhaps A can force B's closure or have it continue?

If this is a correct flow, how do I get the process Id ( I don't know whether there'll be one for QtSingleApplication, or for a process, and if Pid QProcess::processID() ), will be any good? ).

Also, once I have it, how do I force B's closure? Or inform it of any message?

Thank you for your help.